# Error with jQuery Session

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, jquery-session

I'm hoping someone can help me as I'm trying to store relatively simple values into a session with jQuery (values from a select field). I've been trying to use [this plugin here](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin), but it is throwing an error on the page load. The error is as follows...:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function each(iterator, context) {
    try {
      this._each(iterator, context);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e != $break) throw e;
    }
    return this;
} has no method 'split'
```

I've read that this could be a conflict with Prototype so I added the following to the top of the jquery.session.js file and changed all instances of '$' to 'jQuery' to no avail.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

I'm not entirely set on this plugin and would be willing to use a different one if suggested to do so. I'm just hoping it is a quick fix someone is familiar with, or suggestions for another possible solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using prototype.js? I'm afraid this plugin simply won't be compatible with jquery+prototype.js without modifications to the plugin. It appears to be using .split on something that isn't a string, likely due to some core javascript method that prototype.js overrides.

Comment: Do you have an exact line number where this error originates from?

Comment: I have used this plugin with great success:  http://www.jstorage.info/  It works with jquery, prototype, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a site that explains the html5 session storage.
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/